# how to find maximum of series within a vector in R code

Tags: r

I want to get the maximum of each series that is non zero.
For example:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 10, 50, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 6, 5, 44, 0, 0, 1, 2)
```

I want to get 50, 44, 2 in R code.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem a bit?  Do you mean that runs of zeroes act as delimiters for subsequences, and you want the max of each subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `rle`:

```
zero <- rle(x == 0)
y <- sapply(split(x, rep(seq_along(zero$lengths), zero$lengths)), max)
y[y > 0]
##  2  4  6 
## 50 44  2
```

Or, similarly, with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x)[, max(x), rleid(x == 0)][V1 > 0]
##    rleid V1
## 1:     2 50
## 2:     4 44
## 3:     6  2
```